# How Good is use Bigquery ML or SageMaker (AWS)?

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-sagemaker

At work we are lookin to the possibility to make a change in our model environment, as of today we have only Bigquery as our datawarehouse, and we create the models in differents languages (R, python, etc).

We see that there is a Bigquery ML tool and Sagemaker (AWS), but we are kind of skeptical about it, so my question is: Is it worth to make the change to BIGQUERYML or Sagemaker?... Can we do all the step by step process in model development in it? (Feature Selection, Cross validation, Perofmance testing) or is limited?

We are a medium-small fintech-company by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery ML is a powerful tool for machine learning.It is a fully-managed service that lets you train and serve machine learning models using SQL queries. It provides a simple way to build and deploy machine learning models on massive datasets without requiring any infrastructure setup or maintenance.

Yes, it provides feature selection, cross-validation, and performance testing. If you're already using BigQuery as your data warehouse and you're comfortable with SQL queries, then BigQuery ML might be the better choice for you. Here's a great [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/an-end-to-end-machine-learning-model-development-guide-using-bigquery-ml-6a283f5c818d) that will help you get started in BigQuery ML.